# How to download an image that a client uploaded in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a website where users can upload images (part of some report) and I kinda don't know how to save those images.

I think the best way right now is to download those images into a folder of images.

I never really did something like that and everything I tried isn't working.

Here's my code and markup.

HTML markup: the web

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="photoPath" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="photoPath" class="" type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" id="file" accept="image/*" multiple />
            <span asp-validation-for="photoPath" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="display_image" style="display: none; overflow-y: scroll; height: 400px; width: auto;">
            <output id="result" style="overflow-y:scroll; height:400px; width:auto; "></output>
            <script>

                document.querySelector("#file").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
                    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
                        const files = e.target.files;
                        const output = document.querySelector("#result");
                        output.innerHTML = "";
                        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                            if (!files[i].type.match("image")) continue;
                            const picReader = new FileReader();
                            picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                                const picFile = event.target;
                                console.log(picFile.width)
                                const div = document.createElement("div");
                                div.innerHTML = `<img class="form-control" id="thumbnail" src="${picFile.result}" title="${picFile.name}" style="height: 500%;width: 200%;"/>`;
                                output.appendChild(div);
                            });
                            picReader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
                            document.getElementById('display_image').setAttribute("style", "display:inline;width:auto");

                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("Your browser does not support File API");
                    }
                });
            </script>
```

C# : model class

```
public class ReportModel
{
    /*
      Web stuff
    */
    [DisplayName("Add photo")]
    public List<string> photoPath { get; set; }
    /*
      More web stuff
    */
}
```

Comment: You  not posted code behind that would and does save the uploaded file to some folder - we need to see how you doing that file save to the folder. Also, are all users to see and get and to be able to download files from that folder, or is each user ONLY to see their own files they up-loaded? and what happens if two users upload a file called dog.png, then what? So to present a list of files up-loaded by ONE user, then it probably a good idea to create a database table called MyUpLoadedFiles and in that table you place file name, user_id, and file name to enable a display of one user files.

Comment: First, there is no code that does it. I need help doing it.
In the HTML you can see the upload (frontend).
Second, the images are downloaded to the machine which displays them on another page.

Every report has its ID so every case will be in a different folder

Answer (score 1):

Well, we need more details as to how and where you plan to save the files.

Assuming a webforms app?

Then probably better to start using asp.net controls. They work MUCH better with your code behind.

So, say this simple markup:

```
    <div id="MyUpLoadArea" runat="server">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpLoad1" runat="server" onchange="ShowImagePreview(this);"
             AllowMultiple="True" accept="image/*" style="float:left" />

        <asp:Image ID="ImgPrv" Width="160px" runat="server" style="float:left"/>
        <div style="clear:both;height:20px"></div>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdUpLoad" runat="server" Text="Up-Load" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdUpLoad_Click" />
     <script>
         function ShowImagePreview(input) {
             if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                 var reader = new FileReader();
                 reader.onload = function (e) {
                     $('#<%=ImgPrv.ClientID%>').prop('src', e.target.result)
                 };
                 reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
             }
         }
     </script>        
    </div>
```

So, when we select say 4 files, it displays the first one, and we have this:

[image]

So, in above, we have a standard asp.net button we have to click to up-load the files.

The code for that can say be this:

```
   protected void cmdUpLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSQL = "";
        SqlCommand cmdSQL;

        foreach (HttpPostedFile OneFile in FileUpLoad1.PostedFiles)
        {
            string strSaveFile = Server.MapPath("~/UpLoadFiles/");
            strSaveFile += OneFile.FileName;

            OneFile.SaveAs(strSaveFile);
            // now add this row to data base
            strSQL = "INSERT INTO MyUpLoadFiles (FileName, Size, UpLoadTime, User_ID, SavePath) " +
                            "VALUES (@FileName, @Size, @UpLoadTime, @User_ID, @SavePath)";

            cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = OneFile.FileName;
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Size", SqlDbType.Int).Value = OneFile.ContentLength;
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@UpLoadTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@User_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["User_ID"];
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@SavePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "~/UpLoadFiles/" + OneFile.FileName;
            General.MyRstE(cmdSQL);
        }

        // ALL files saved, display the grid of up-loaded files
        strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM MyUpLoadFiles 
                   WHERE User_ID = " + Session["User_ID"].ToString() +
                   " ORDER BY UpLoadTime DESC ";
        cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
        DataTable rstFiles = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);

        GridView1.DataSource = rstFiles;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        MyUpLoadArea.Style.Add("display", "none"); // hide up-load area
        MyFileView.Style.Add("display", "normal"); // show file grid

    }
```

so, we send/save all files to the folder MyUpLoadFiles.

We save each file into a database - so we can list them out later, and show ONLY the one users file(s).

So, right below the above div and markup, I have a gridview, like this:

```
    <div id="MyFileView" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
           AutoGenerateColumns = "False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" CssClass="table"
           width="50%" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UpLoadTime" HeaderText="UpLoaded" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" width="120px"
                            ImageUrl = '<% # Eval("SavePath") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">                  
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdDownLoad" runat="server" Text="Download" CssClass="btn"  />
                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

So, now when I hit up-load button, I get/see this:

[image]

We of course need to wire up a event for the download button.

Say, this:

```
     <asp:Button ID="cmdDownLoad" runat="server" Text="Download" CssClass="btn"
      OnClick="cmdDownLoad_Click"    />
```

And that code could be:

```
    protected void cmdDownLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button myBut = sender as Button;
        GridViewRow gRow = myBut.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

        string strFileOnly = gRow.Cells[0].Text;
        string strFile = "";
        strFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/UpLoadFiles/" + strFileOnly);

        string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strFileOnly);
        Response.ContentType = sMineType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileOnly);
        Response.TransmitFile(strFile);
        Response.End();
    }
```

I also have two helper routines MyRstP and MyRstE - they are just some general code routines I have (became VERY tired of typing code over and over to get a simple conneciton string setup, and then execute some code to return a table, or to execute some sql code. So, those two routines were this:

```
    public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
    public static void MyRstE(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Not really much important - but the above two routines are handy, and thus I don't type that code over and over for simple and general data operations.